# Date Conversion from nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column which stores date as "Mon, 02 Nov 2015". The column data type is nvarchar(255). I would like to convert this to date format as "dd-mm-yyyy".

Please help.

Comment: It's a good idea to store all dates in a date column.  Benefits include reduced storage space and easy access to all of SQL Servers date functions (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186724.aspx).  The answers below would still allow you to format the date as you please when presenting your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CONVERT()` , `CHAR()` / `VARCHAR()` :

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105)

result: 10-12-2015
```

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

Comment: This converts a `datetime` to a `varchar`, which was not the question

Comment: I fail to see how this can be the correct, accepted answer. It doesn't do what OP asked

Comment: @HoneyBadger , if you will understand further the OP , he is not really asking to convert the value to datetime, when he says `date format as "dd-mm-yyyy".` , the op is asking how to do the output that formats it to `dd-mm-yyyy`

Comment: Probably, yeah. But OP has a varchar in a particular format which is the problem. Not a datetime

Comment: OP asked how to convert a string like "Mon, 02 Nov 2015" into a string in format dd-mm-yyyy. What your code does, is convert a date to a string in format dd-mm-yyyy. How is OP going to use your code on a varchar(255) attribute?

Comment: Oh i see, but it seems that the answer is correct ? , or maybe the OP and my answer is wrong , and you're correct ? :) anyways , this question already have an answer.. so it doesn't make any sense to argue with it because the OP already have a solution for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here, 105 may be the convert code your looking for

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ISNULL(@yourDate, ''), 105)
```

Comment: This converts to a `varchar`, 105 is format `dd-mm-yyyy`, not `day, dd-mm-yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

Convert method converts the date to specified style. Here 105 indicates the style mm/dd/yyyy

`CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),105)`
By varying the style date can be converted to various styles.

Comment: This converts a datetime to a varchar, which was not the question

Answer (score 1):

You first need to remove de day-name, then you can convert to datetime. If needed you can then convert back to varchar. Always keep datetime values in a datetime datatype!

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING('Mon, 02 Nov 2015', 5, 12), 105)
```

**EDIT**

The above query returns a `datetime`, which, contrary to what @JapzDivino suggests, doesn't have a format.
To get the format specified use:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING('Mon, 02 Nov 2015', 5, 12), 105), 105)
```

Result: `02-11-2015`

Comment: You query output is `2015-11-02 00:00:00.000` , this includes the exact time stamp.. the OP is asking how to format his output into `dd-mm-yyyy` format.

Comment: now you have the correct format and correct answer/output.. look at your query now.. in the end, you also convert the datetime into varchar :) .. and that is correct :)

Comment: @JapzDivino Yeah, but I start with a varchar, convert that to datetime, convert that to varchar in the correct format. That is correct, your answer still is not

Comment: the bottom line is.. your result now is still a `varchar` , and my point is why do you need so many conversion if you will have the same datatype and the same format/answer in the end with only one conversion :)

Comment: @JapzDivino, you need the conversions, because it is the only way to do what OP asked. See also my comment to your answer.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to argue with it , because the OP already have an answer.. anyways thanks :) have a great day ahead.

Comment: @Japongskie (Name change? :P), if you agree my answer gives a correct result, you could remove your downvote

Comment: yup i change my name to display my gaming name :) since you have the correct result now, downvote removed :) have a great day ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
Declare @t as nvarchar(255)
set @t='Mon, 02 Nov 2015'
select CONVERT(date,ISNULL(substring(@t,5,LEN(@t)), ''),105)
```